# Short cut to navigate when terminal is showing man page in MacOS

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, manpage

I'm using MacOS Lion 10.7.2.
Whenever, I use the command `man`, the terminal show the waring as the image below. It ask me press RETURN to continue.
[image]

After that, I navigate the content by press RETURN key (the carriage-return key). It only go forward the content line by line. I can't:

- show all the content or go forward the content page by page
- go back the content

Please help me. What is the short cuts? Thank you!

EDIT:

when I run: `echo $TERM`, it shows:

`xterm-256color`

My problem is: When the Terminal is showing the content of the command (man [command]):

- Press ENTER to move down
- how to move up?

Comment: edit your post to include the value of `echo TERM=$TERM` from the command-line. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fix this by properly setting the terminal type in the settings for the OS X `Terminal.app`. Open the application's Settings window, select the Startup tab and note which settings group is being used, select the Settings tab and then the settings group noted, select the Advanced tab, and make sure the terminal type (`Declare terminal as:`) is set to something appropriate, like `xterm-256color`.  Then open a new terminal window and enter:

```
echo $TERM
```

If the terminal type value displayed is not the one you chose, examine your shell profile files to ensure they do not contain a line that modifies the TERM variable.  If your default shell is `bash`, the default files to check are `.bash_profile` and any files referenced from within it.